# Why is wget skipping files while trying to mirror a site

Tags: wget, curl, download, mirror

I ran wget on this site: http://demo.codestag.com/geeklove/ but it only returns a single index.html

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains --no-parent http://demo.codestag.com/geeklove
```

I tried spoofing the useragent like here : http://www.askapache.com/linux/wget-header-trick.html#Testing_Wget_Trick but still no go.

When I used the --debug option it showed that it skipped all the other pages.

Comment: Tell us the exact options you passed to `wget`.

Comment: @scai I have added the command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `--domains` specifies a list of domains to be followed. Because you don't specify anything after this option wget downloads only those files directly specified.

If you remove this option or replace it with `--domains demo.codestag.com` then wget will still refuse to download more files due to the *robots.txt* on this server. To ignore this file you have to specify `-e robots=off`.

If you run into further problems it is always helpful to specify `-d` (`--debug`) to see what bothers wget.